# Spark ALS Recommendation engine with prior clustering

Tags: recommender-system, spark-mllib

I'm trying to develop a recommendation engine, but since the dataset is too big, I'm trying to divide users in clusters and run the ALS recommender on each single cluster.

To do this, I'm trying to follow [these](https://spark-summit.org/2015-east/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SSE15-18-Neumann-Alla.pdf) slides by J.Neumann & S.Alla, shown at Spark Summit East 2015, which show an approach to cluster users according to their implicit feedbacks.

Right now I'm implementing the clustering Batch process (description starts at p. 8, implementation at p.12)

But I'm having a problem with the code:

```
val mf_model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, n, lambda, alpha)
// ...
val productSVD = productRowMatrix.computeSVD(svdRank)
val userFeatures = userRowMatrix.multiply(productSVD.V)
    .multiply(Matrices.diag(productSVD.s))
val cluster_model = KMeans(userFeatures.rows,numClusters,numIter)
```

When `rank != svdRank` I get an error in

```
val user2cluster=
    mf_model.userFeatures.map(
        (bHashToUser.value(_._1),
        //bClusterData = sc.broadcast(cluster_model)
        bClusterData.value.predict(Vectors.dense(_._2)))
```

Because the training of the k-Means model was done with Vectors of length `svdRank` and it's being asked to predict the result for vectors of length `rank`.

1. Am I missing something or `svdRank` has to be equal to `rank`?
2. Why are the training and the prediction done in different feature spaces?

Comment: First, do not cross-post, as this is against StackExchange policy. Second, it is off-topic in here as it's a software oriented question - so it fits rather SO.

Comment: @Tim with all respect, I think that my two questions are more related to statistical/mathematical principles and barely related to the code. So I closed my question on SO.

Comment: It's about problems with running Spark code...

Comment: @Tim it's about the mathematical principles behind the code, plus there's a "spark-mllib" tag on this site. The slides that i linked show mathematical principles behind the used code. I'm asking if it's correct to use different feature spaces for training and prediction, I'm not asking things related to spark/scala.